# contents of the elements of the struct array change after some time

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <crypt.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <assert.h>

  struct user {
  char* username;
  char* name;
  char* saltandhash;
  char* state;
  };

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 { 

   if ( argc != 3 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
  {
    printf("usage: %s passwd-path shadow-path", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  char* passwd = argv[1];
  char* shadow = argv[2];

  //file reading variables for passwd and shadow files
  FILE* fp_shadow;
  FILE* fp_passwd;
  char* line_shadow = NULL;
  char* line_passwd = NULL;
  size_t len_shadow = 0;
  size_t len_passwd = 0;
  ssize_t read_shadow;
  ssize_t read_passwd;
  //file reading for dictionary
  FILE* fp_dict;
  char* line_dict = NULL;
  size_t len_dict = 0;
  ssize_t read_dict;
  const char* dict = "top250short.txt";

  fp_shadow = fopen(shadow, "r");
  if (fp_shadow == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  fp_passwd = fopen(passwd, "r");
  if(fp_passwd == NULL)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  int first_time = 1;
  int found = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  struct user users[8196];
  struct user u = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
  char salt[6];
  char* username = NULL;
  char* saltandhash = NULL; 
  char* name = NULL;

  while ((read_shadow = getline(&line_shadow, &len_shadow, fp_shadow)) != -1) {

    //Handle shadow file
    username = strdup(strsep(&line_shadow, ":"));
    saltandhash = strdup(strsep(&line_shadow, ":"));

    if(first_time){
     int i;
       for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
         salt[i] = saltandhash[i];
       }
      first_time = 0;
     }

    //handle passwd file
    read_passwd = getline(&line_passwd, &len_passwd, fp_passwd);
    if(read_passwd == -1)
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    strsep(&line_passwd, ":");
    strsep(&line_passwd, ":");
    strsep(&line_passwd, ":");
    strsep(&line_passwd, ":");
    name = strdup(strsep(&line_passwd, ":"));

    u.username = strdup(username);
    u.name = strdup(name);
    u.saltandhash = strdup(saltandhash);
    u.state = strdup("NF"); //not found
    users[counter] = u;

    printf("%s***%s***%s\n", users[0].username, users[0].saltandhash, users[0].state);
    counter++;
 }
   return 0;
}
```

In this code, I attempt to read from the passwd and shadow files and store the values I parse in an array of structs.

passwd file looks like this:

```
 mly460:x:1002:1002:Michael Lily,,,:/home/mly460:/bin/sh
 (and similar lines)
```

shadow file looks like this:

```
 mly460:$1$R5$yo1/aN8VtX54qAf1W8Rhe0:16458::::::
 (and similar lines)
```

Output of this program when run ./executable passwd-path shadow-path

```
mly460***$1$R5$yo1/aN8VtX54qAf1W8Rhe0***NF
mly460***$1$R5$yo1/aN8VtX54qAf1W8Rhe0***NF
mly460***$1$R5$yo1/aN8VtX54qAf1W8Rhe0***NF
tcsh
***$1$R5$yo1/aN8VtX54qAf1W8Rhe0***NF
***$1$R5$yo1/aN8VtX54qAf1W8Rhe0***NF
***59:/bin/tcsh
***NF
***011***NF
***011***Calvert,,,
***011***Calvert,,,
:::
***011***Calvert,,,
1$R5$Z8T2h9IbKpHEhVouZOXIt1***011***Calvert,,,
1$R5$Z8T2h9IbKpHEhVouZOXIt1***16415::::::
***Calvert,,,
1$R5$Z8T2h9IbKpHEhVouZOXIt1***bwm505***
1$R5$Z8T2h9IbKpHEhVouZOXIt1***bwm505***$kMLZJaGeDjfu0e3d5XZM/1
1$R5$Z8T2h9IbKpHEhVouZOXIt1***bwm505***$kMLZJaGeDjfu0e3d5XZM/1
1$R5$Z8T2h9IbKpHEhVouZOXIt1***bwm505***$kMLZJaGeDjfu0e3d5XZM/1
(and the rest is the same line.)
```

As you can see at the end I'm always printing out the contents of the struct which is stored in the 0th position in the users array.

What is weird is that the contents of the 0th element CHANGE as the while loop progresses, but stabilizes to a certain value after some point.

And, in the output the ordering is mixed. first it prints out the "saltandhash" part and then the username, which is not the case in the printf statement. (in the first three lines of the output this is not the case. Order is preserved there.)

Can anyone help me with this weird behavior? Thanks

Edit(answer found): strsep function was messing up line_shadow and line_paswd variables. The solution is copying them over to some temporary char* before parsing them like:

```
char* copy_to_parse = strdup(line_shadow);
```

Comment: DUDE. Thanks for pointing this out. Editing answer to reflect your answer in code. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question to show it as solved.